# How do i implement a pop out in panel like that of avast 9 application

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How do i implement a pop out in panel like that of avast 9 application.
I was able to implement the  of the control but the problem is making the control stay open until the mouse is hovered out of the control region.
The code is :

```
 Private Sub btnCourseRegistration_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCourseRegistration.MouseHover
        TabControlSubMenu.Visible = True
        TabControlSubMenu.SelectedTab = TabPageCourseRegistrationSubMenu

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCourseRegistration_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCourseRegistration.MouseLeave

        If TabControlSubMenu.Focused = False Then
            TabControlSubMenu.Visible = False
        Else
            TabControlSubMenu.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TabControlSubMenu_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabControlSubMenu.MouseLeave
        TabControlSubMenu.Visible = False
    End Sub.
```